# NextJS app builds fine locally but fails when deploying to Vercel (FetchError)

Tags: deployment, next.js, build, environment-variables, strapi

Fairly new to web dev and I'm trying to build fullstack for the first time.

I've built a simple blog using Next as frontend and Strapi as the backend. The app works fine locally but I'm stuck at deployment. I figure it's some sort of a connection issue with the backend (which is still running locally) or I'm totally missing something on the frontend. Is it that I need to make Strapi available online first and then use that domain in my fetch?

Vercel throws this error during build:

```
FetchError: request to http://localhost:1337/api/places?populate=%2A failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1337
at ClientRequest.
```

This is how I'm getting data from Strapi

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  // const postRes = await axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/articles?populate=*");
  const reviewsRes = await fetchAPI("/articles", { populate: ["image", "place"] });

  return {
    // props: { reviews: postRes.data.data },
    props: { reviews: reviewsRes.data },
  };
}
```

I'm also using this line to bring in images and data

```
backgroundImage: `url(${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL}${place.attributes.image.data.attributes.url})`,
```

I've also tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1:1337 in my env/config

Answer (score 0):

You've actually answered your question in this line:

> Is it that I need to make Strapi available online first and then use that domain in my fetch?

Yes! You have to deploy your Strapi backend first, and use the domain/URL inside your deployed NextJS frontend.

> Strapi Deployment Documentation: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/deployment.html

What you're doing with the `backgroundImage` url is what you need to do to your data-fetching url.

Use that `NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL` env variable so you don't have to change the code before deploying.

Locally you can have .env file in you NextJS root folder something like this

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL=http://localhost:1337/api
```

Then, once you've deployed the NextJS app to Vercel, you have to set the `NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL` variable to the project setting.

> Set env variables in Vercel: https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables

Welcome to web dev world! Hope it helps!